# Compare Arrays to Object Properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

How do you compare an array to an object w/ pairs of keys/values (properties:values) in Javascript?

Here is how i would do it if they were just arrays:

```
                       for (var l = 0; l < vm.statesNotAvailable.length; l++)
                        {
                            for (var m = 0 ; m < vm.statesNotAvailable.length; m++)
                            {
                                //Maps the values to their keys inside  vm.statesArray
                                if (vm.statesNotAvailable[l] == vm.statesWithCodes[m]) {

                                    delete vm.statesWithCodes.m;

                                }
                            }
                        }
```

This is how i would do it if they were both objects:

```
          for (var key in object) {
                            if (vm.statesNotAvailable.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                //Now, object[key] is the current value
                                if (vm.statesNotAvailable[key] === vm.statesArray[key] )
                                    delete object[key];
                            }
                        }
```

However, neither of these work for me. So, how do i delete the keys from my object that intersect with the values inside the array, despite index (position)?

Comment: Like i said: i'm trying to compare values of elements in an array to values of the properties within an object.

Comment: They are not the same data structure, no. An array won't have properties, they just have indices with "stuff" in the elements (could be values, could be arrays, could be objects, could be etc.). Whereas, objects will have properties in terms of key/value pairs (i.e. vm.statesWithCodes.Alabama is the key w/ value "AL" -- i'm mapping states as properties w/ the 2-digit state name as the value of that particular property). Does that help clarify what the difference between an array and an object is?

Comment: You have a (key, value) from an object.  Are you just looking to see if that value is ANYWHERE in the array and if so, you want to remove it from the object?

Comment: Posting an example of the two data structures you're trying to compare would also be helpful.

Comment: vm.statesNotAvailable
2014-10-17 10:31:19.855[Array[1]0: "Alabama"length: 1__proto__: Array[0], Array[1]0: "Alaska"length: 1__proto__: ...
vm.statesWithCodes
2014-10-17 10:31:23.635Object {Alabama: "AL", Alaska: "AK", Arizona: "AZ", Arkansas: "AR", California: "CA"…}

Comment: Like i was saying: i'm trying to delete the keys from my object that intersect with the values inside the array, despite index (position).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
                        //Iterates through properties of object
                        for (var property in vm.statesWithCodes)
                        {
                            //Iterates through indices of array
                            for (var m = 0 ; m < vm.statesNotAvailable.length; m++)
                             {
                                //Compares keys of object w/ values of array
                                if (property == vm.statesNotAvailable[m])
                                {
                                    //Deletes the property sequentially
                                    delete vm.statesWithCodes[property];
                                }
                            }
                        }
```